# Using String templates "|" Across Multiple Lines

Tags: concatenation, abap

Is there any way to use the `|` string operator across multiple lines?

Using the classic `CONCATENATE` token, you can make assignments like the following:

```
CONCATENATE 'A rubber duck is a toy shaped like a stylized'
            'duck, generally yellow with a flat base. It'
            'may be made of rubber or rubber-like material' 
            'such as vinyl plastic.' INTO lv_variable SEPARATED BY space.
```

I've not found a valid way to do something like the following:

```
lv_variable = |A rubber duck is a toy shaped like a stylized | &
              |duck, generally yellow with a flat base. It | &
              |may be made of rubber or rubber-like material | &
              |such as vinyl plastic.|.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this, or are you constrained to one line when working with the `|` operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
data : lv_variable type string.

lv_variable = |A rubber duck is a toy shaped like a stylized| &&
              |duck, generally yellow with a flat base. It | &&
              |may be made of rubber or rubber-like material | &&
              |such as vinyl plastic.|.

write lv_variable.
```

Comment: **Just as additional info:** For String templates (|) and literal-only strings (\`) `&&` and `&` are the same. Both will get executed during runtime and no character length limit is applied. For "common" strings (') `&&` executes during runtime and removes trailing blanks on the other hand `&` executes at compilation and restricts the two joined strings to a maximum of 255 characters each.